# Java: What is Java's alternative to JavaScript's localeCompare()?

Tags: javascript, java, locale

I am trying to sort the `JSONObject` array in **Java**. Can someone please tell me how can I sort based on `locale` in **Java** just similar to JavaScript's `localeCompare()`?

In JavaScript, we can do locale sort like below,
`arr.sort( ( a, b ) => a.data[ "nested-name" ].localeCompare(b.data[ "nested-name" ]) )`

I want to do locale compared sorting in Java.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html

Comment: [Performing Locale-Independent Comparisons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/locale.html) in the tutorial

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`Collator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html):

```java
Collator collator = Collator.getInstance();

Arrays.sort(array, (JSONObject o1, JSONObject o2) ->
                collator.compare(o1.get("data"), o2.get("data")));
```

---

Here's a complete example with a collator that uses the default locale to compare an array of JSON objects based on their `data` property:

```java
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class LocaleCompareTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONObject a = new JSONObject();
        a.put("data", "a");

        JSONObject b = new JSONObject();
        b.put("data", "b");

        JSONObject[] array = new JSONObject[]{b, a};

        Collator collator = Collator.getInstance();

        Arrays.sort(array, (JSONObject o1, JSONObject o2) ->
                collator.compare(o1.get("data"), o2.get("data")));

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

This yields the following output:

```json
[{"data":"a"}, {"data":"b"}]
```

---

See the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) for more information on how to configure your collator for your desired locale and collation rules.